# Verbatim/listings in beamerposter?

Tags: listings, verbatim, beamerposter

I have prepared some nice posters using [`beamerposter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter), but now I came to a poster where I would like to add a few lines of code.

By just adding `[fragile]` to the frame I get an error:

```
File ended while scanning use of \next
```

How could I obtain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the extent of your verbatim needs, the `verbatimbox` package might help.  It will allow you to create the verbatim content and stick it into a LaTeX savebox prior to entering the `frame`.  Then, in the frame, merely recall the savebox.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}{\VerbA}
!@#$%^&*()_
here is a test$%!
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}[\Huge]{\VerbB}
!@#$%^&*()_
Here is another Test&*{}@\
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{frame}
\fbox{\VerbA}  \quad and\quad \VerbB
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]